# flutter displaying different types of images in child

Tags: image, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am doing something funky. The user is allowed to choose images from his phone's gallery or take a picture with his camera.

I then upload that image to `Firebase storage` and retrieve the `URL` to save it to `firestore`, so that I can reference that image when the user wants to edit his selections.

That portion works great.

When the edit page opens, there is a quick error that displays, but the image still displays. I want to get rid of that "quick error".

this is the error I get before the image is loaded:

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

the other problem I do not know what image is being loaded into my variable it can a FILE (user can change the image from his gallery/camera) or a string (URL from firestore, displaying image that was previously selected)

my wonderful nested:

```
child: (imageFile1 != null)
                    ? Image.file(
                        imageFile1,
                        width: (size.width - 8 * 4) * 0.33,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )
                    : (imageList[0] == null)
                        ? Image.asset(
                            defaultImage,
                            width: (size.width - 8 * 4) * 0.33,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          )
                        : Image.network(
                            imageList[0],
                            width: (size.width - 8 * 4) * 0.33,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
```

`imagelist` gets loaded in the `initstate` (Therefore, I have a method with Future and await involved to go fetch that information from `firetsore`)
`imageFile1` gets loaded when the user decides to change the image to another one from his gallery/camera
`default image`, if both are null then display missing image jpg.

I tried debugging and it seems the scaffold is being called before the initstate??? Which is strange to me...

Thoughts?

Comment: How did you initialise imageList?

Comment: get all information from firestore in my firestore service dart file. then I return a documentsnapshot.data() back to the original page and I can access all my values from there. Everything works, just that before my app loads the images, it sees it as null and, therefore, throws a split second error, but recovers and places all the correct information in my form. I just want to get rid of that split second error...

Comment: so in my init I call a future function that has an await to retrieve the documentsnapshot.data(), while it is doing that it jumps to build my form with initial values (which will be null since the data was not received yet). then it goes back to the await to finish the rest of future function (which includes image list and other information that I am trying to preload my form with) that's the issue right there! So, I did null checking but now it only display my default values and not the snapshot values... :(

Answer (score 1):

We could avoid address this issue by the means of a `CircularProgressIndicator` that will be drawn while the `imageList[]` is empty:

```
child: imageList == null || imageList.isEmpty() ? CircularProgressIndicator() : _buildImageFiles(),
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is how I did it....First, thank you all for your inputs

My `Scaffold` I already had `CircularProgressIndicator` implemented with `Visibility` widget and having the `visible paramter: isLoading`

so, before and after my await call in the Future function (this function gets called in the inistate function) I did a `setState` of `isloading = true/false`.
This part was key since I needed it to pre-load my form components with the data coming from Firestore.

That solves my pre-loading form data.

As for null imagelist.... I ended up with this freakishly looking nested if statement

```
(imageList.isEmpty)
                        ? Image.asset(
                            defaultImage,
                            width: (size.width - 8 * 4) * 0.33,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          )
                        : (imageFile1 != null)
                            ? Image.file(
                                imageFile1,
                                width: (size.width - 8 * 4) * 0.33,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              )
                            : (imageList[0] == null)
                                ? Image.asset(
                                    defaultImage,
                                    width: (size.width - 8 * 4) * 0.33,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  )
                                : Image.network(
                                    imageList[0],
                                    width: (size.width - 8 * 4) * 0.33,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
```